# Print a string from ArrayList of String[] per Index?

Tags: java, arraylist

How to print `ArrayList` of `String[]` into `String` per index
with expected Output like this

```
Nama: John
Kimia: 10
biologi: 9
fisika: 8

Nama: Peter
Kimia: 7
biologi: 8
fisika: 10

Nama: Steve
Kimia: 6
biologi: 9
fisika: 8
```

Here is the code and how to print it?

```
public static String dataSiswa(ArrayList<String[]> list_Siswa){

    for (String[] dataSiswa : list_Siswa){
        String nama = dataSiswa[0];
        String kimia = dataSiswa[1];
        String biologi = dataSiswa[2];
        String fisika = dataSiswa[3];

        data = "Nama: " + nama;
    }
    return data;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were pretty close to it:

```
public static String dataSiswa(ArrayList<String[]> list_Siswa){

    String data = "";
    for (String[] dataSiswa : list_Siswa){
        data += "Nama: " + dataSiswa[0] + "\n" +
                "Kimia" + dataSiswa[1] + "\n" +
                "Biologi" + dataSiswa[2] + "\n" +
                "Fisika" + dataSiswa[3] + "\n\n";
    }
    return data;
}
```

This generates your `String` to be outputted. Printing:

```
System.out.print(yourArrayList);
```

Just don't forget to initialize `yourArrayList` prior of the method call.

Answer (score 0):

Recommend using a `StringBuilder` and appending the desired values together with a `\n` at the end for a new line. General form could look like this:

```
  public static String dataSiswa(ArrayList<String[]> list_Siswa){
    String[] sections = {"Nama: ", "Kimia: ", "biologi: ", "fisika: "};
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
    
    for (String[] dataSiswa : list_Siswa) {
        for(int i = 0; i < dataSiswa.length; i++) {
          builder.append(sections[i]).append(dataSiswa[i]).append("\n");
        }
        builder.append("\n"); //Extra space between data chunks added here
    }
    
    return builder.toString();
  }
```

Comment: Nama: John
Kimia: 10
biologi: 9
fisika: 8

Nama: Peter
Kimia: 7
biologi: 8
fisika: 10

Nama: Steve
Kimia: 6
biologi: 9
fisika: 8

How to get the value break line for each data?

Comment: @JansenStanlie The inner loop is where each chunk of data is being built. Just add a `builder.append("\n");` after that loop as part of the outer loop.